# How do I properly use the java.lang.Math?

Tags: java, math, multiplication

I am in a COMP 110 class which is intro to Java. This specific program is irrelevant to the class but to help my own understanding with Java.

I believe I have imported the tool to allow the program to calculate basic math operations by using "java.lang.Math;"

I understand * is multiplication, / is division, + is addition, - is subtraction, and % finds the remainder.

The final line of the program gives me the error message:

```
squared.java:14: operator * cannot be applied to java.lang.String,java.lang.String
```

and I am at a loss for why because I have imported the language Math, which should enable me to use the * to multiply the value variable when I enter "value * value"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.lang.Math;

public class squared {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What number do you want to find the square of?");

        String value = number.nextLine();

        System.out.println("The square of the number" + value + "is" + value * value);

    }
}
```

Comment: Because `value` is a `String`, not a numeric type.

Comment: What is the result of `you're doing` * `it wrong`? multiplying strings is not easy :(.

Comment: You don't need to import `java.lang.Math` to do this. You do, however, need numeric types to do maths.

Comment: @Tom lol. Great explaination, +1 :)

Comment: Everything in `java.lang` is automatically imported.  If you want something from `Math`, you would say `Math.sin(x)` (for example) (you can also use a "static import").  But that's not the problem in this case.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yep, changing it to double fixed the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes you must first convert it into an Integer, Double, Float, etc in order to do a multiplication on such. So just do

```
int v = Integer.parseInt(value.trim());
```

Then

```
System.out.println("The square of the number"+v+"is"+ (v * v));
```

Also using operators has nothing to do with Math library. Math library is used like so:

```
  double d = Double.parseDouble(value.trim());
  Math.pow(d,2.0); //which does the same thing above
```

Comment: Or he could define `value` differently: `int value = number.nextInt();`

Comment: @Tom yes that is another way of doing it

Comment: @Rika you want to do trim or it going to give number format exception as there is a new line at the end. :)

Comment: The program runs now. From my understanding, using a "String" to do math in Java doesn't work. Int, float, or double would work.  Whenever I want to do a mathematical problem I'll use "double" because it allows decimals and int doesn't. Will this be ok granted nobody will enter a number bigger than double allows.

Comment: @wrongAnswer And where should that line separator come from? `nextLine()` excludes it. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

Comment: @ChristopherBabayans applying blanket rules without understanding is a recipe for disaster. `int` is used for integral types. `double` is a floating point type which is double precision, i.e. it is subject to [floating-point rounding error](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-do-computers-suck-at-math/) so the number will not necessarily be the same as that entered by the user. The correct representation depends on what you are representing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to go about this program -

1) Read the input as `String` and then convert it to `int` or

2) Read the input as `int`(or `double`?) itself.

Following code shows how you can read the input as `int` and perform the operation.
Note the code change `(value*value)` in your sysout statement. When you concatenate any value to a string, it get treated as string, and hence you are getting the error. Put it in parenthesis such that before concatenating, actual `value*value` operation is performed.

```
public class squared {

          public static void main(String[] args){

                 Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);

                 System.out.println("What number do you want to find the square of?");

                 int value = number.nextInt();

                 System.out.println("The square of the number"+value+"is"+ (value * value));

          }      
}
```

Talking about `Math.pow()`, it doesn't serve any different purpose here. Using it is same as the way you have done here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to import `java.lang.Math`. All of the `java.lang` libraries are already there. Also, you don't need to use the Math library for operations. You use it for things like `Math.sin()` to find the sine of an angle, or `Math.pow()` to get the power of one number to another. If you want a full list of the uses for `java.lang.Math`, here is a link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

You probably want to store the input in a double, so rather than using `number.nextLine()`, you may want to use `number.nextDouble()`, and store it in a double, as below.

```
double value = number.nextDouble();
```

You were storing the value as a String, so the computer was reading the input as a quotation, like "cat," rather than the numbers. It doesn't work because what you were trying to do was akin to saying 
`"cat" * "dog."`

Good luck in the class!